# Calling instantiate tactic from OCaml in Coq

Tags: ocaml, coq, theorem-proving

I am trying to develop a Coq tactic in OCaml, where I have constructed a `constr` term and now want to instantiate an existential variable in the goal with this term. I m trying to invoke the `Evar_tactic.instantiate` tactic ; but it expects an argument of type  `Tacinterp.interp_sign * Glob_term.glob_constr`. Is there anyway to convert `constr` to this type? Or any other way by which I can instantiate evars from OCaml level?

Secondly, there are tactics called `set` and `pose` in Coq. I could not find where they are defined. If I want to use them from OCaml, how should I do it?